# Accessing a List out of order in Jinja

Tags: python, django, django-views, jinja2

I have setup the following list of lists being passed through to my Jinja template:

> [(u'2nd Principle', 1, 1, 3, 33, 1, 100), (u'Test Principle', 1, 2, 6, 33, 1, 100)]

And thus far I am handling displaying this in a table as follows:

```
<tbody>
   {% for p in performance %}
     <tr>
        {% for a in p %}<td>{{ a }}</td>{% endfor %}
     </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

This works perfectly in printing out each of the lists as a row. However, I have been trying to work with the same list in a different view where I want to show one less item and in a different order.

However, the following does not seem to work for me:

```
<tbody>
   {% for p in performance %}
     <tr>
         <td>{{ p[6] }}</td>
         <td>{{ p[1] }}</td>
         <td>{{ p[3] }}</td>
         <td>{{ p[2] }}</td>
         <td>{{ p[5] }}</td>
         <td>{{ p[6] }}</td>
     </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

The above throws the following error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '[6]' from 'p[6]'

How do I access list items directly without looping through it?

Comment: Purposefully left out in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be using Jinja at all here. Although Jinja is now an option in Django, the default is to use the built-in template language, and that appears to be what you are using. In that syntax, all lookups are done with dot notation:

```
 <td>{{ p.6 }}</td>
```

etc.

Comment: This is super insightful. All this time I presumed this was using Jinja.